# Advice on Henri Cohen's Number Theory books

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

I am a graduate student willing to learn Number Theory. I have come across Henri Cohen's "Number Theory" (Vol. I and II) and I would like to hear from someone who has read these books before: are they comprehensive and clear? Is there any particular topic which is not so well covered? I apologize if the question seems vague but any comments regarding these books would be appreciated, since I have not been able to find anything elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, the books are very good. However, I cannot believe that you cannot find "anything elsewhere".

Comment: For instance on google I found the review https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/number-theory-volume-1-tools-and-diophantine-equations pretty easily (my exact query was "ams book review cohen number theory")

Comment: "comprehensive"? A comprehensive presentation of Number Theory would fill two hundred volumes, not two. [But don't let that put you off studying Number Theory – there's a lot you can do with what you learn from one or two well-chosen texts]